# Dynamic Pages - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, dynamic-pages

**Update:**

I have tried Sheldon's code below but I have struck a couple of issues:

1. When using the line `$this->load->view($page->template, array('content' => $page->content), TRUE);`Unable to load the requested file .php but if I change it to `$page->content` it works fine.
2. When I place the index functions into my other controllers it still loads the default home controller despite what the uri segment is set to.  How do I adjust the model for this to work?

**Original Question:**

I have a template.php file which houses my main site structure. Suppose I have a page called 'home'. I would like to set the `$title` and the `$content` data from the database.

I have set a view for each page and also a controller. I have tried:

```
$this->cms_pages->name;
```

This produces nothing. I know I need to get the URI segment but because I am using `/$sales->name` I am unsure if I have to change it to `$sales->id` for this to work. I would like to get it by the name. Best practices are also important.

Is there a way that I could do something like: `$this->cms_pages->id->1->name`?

**Model**

```
function getCMSPages() {

    $query = $this->db->get('pages');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) return $query->result();
}
```

**Template**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
$data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
$data['title'] = 'Ccho';
$data['content'] = $this->load->view('home', NULL, TRUE);
$this->load->view('template', $data);
}
}
```

**Template**

```
 $stylesheetCSS = array('href' => 'includes/css/style.css', 'rel' => 'stylesheet',   'type' => 'text/css', 'media' => 'print');

echo doctype('html5');
?>
<head>
 <title>Housemovers : <?php echo $title ?></title>
  <?php echo link_tag($stylesheetCSS);?>
   </head>
 <body>
<div id ="wrapper">
<header>
<p>content</p>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
    <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')): ?>
        <li><?php echo anchor('#','Edit Pages');?>
        <?php if(is_array($cms_pages)): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($cms_pages as $page): ?>
                    <li><a href="<?=$page->title?>"><?= $page->title?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <li><?php echo anchor('#','Gallery');?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/addgallery','Add Gallery');?></li>
            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/uploadimage','Upload Image');?>
            </li>
            <li><?php echo anchor('#','Delete Gallery');?></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><?php echo anchor('#','Sales');?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/addsale','Add Sale');?></li>
            <li><?php echo anchor('#','Edit Sale');?>
            <?php if(is_array($sales_pages)): ?>
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach($sales_pages as $sale): ?>
                    <li><a href="editsale/index/<?=$sale->id?>"><?= $sale->name?></a></li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>

            <li><?php echo anchor('#','Delete Sale');?></li>
            <li><?php echo anchor('admin/home/logout','Log Out');?></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    <?php else: ?>
    <ul>
    <li><?php echo anchor('home','Home');?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('about','About Us');?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('gallery','Gallery');?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('testimonials', 'Testimonials');?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('sales','Sales');?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('contact','Contact Us');?></li>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
 <section id="content">
    <h1><?= $title ?></h1>

    <p><?= $content ?></p>

</section>

<footer>&copy; Houses LTD <?php echo date('Y');?></footer>
</div> <!-- Wrapper Close -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @davzie said;

**Model**

```
function getCMSPage($page_name = '') {

    if(!$page_name) $page_name= 'home'; // home be default.    
    $this->db->where('name', $page_name);
    $query = $this->db->get('pages', 1);
    if($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row();
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function index()
{
$page = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPage($this-uri->segment(1)); // pretend the first segment in your URI is the page you want.
$data['cms_pages'] = $this->navigation_model->getCMSPages();
$data['title'] = $page->name;
$data['content'] = $this->load->view($page->template, array('content' => $page->content), TRUE);
$this->load->view('template', $data);
}
```

}

Comment: Sheldom,  I now get Unable to load the requested file .php

Comment: Sorry Jess,I should have explained more.
the line
`code`$data['content'] = $this->load->view($page->template, array('content' => $page->content), TRUE);

the var $page->template should come from your database, so add a field in your structure. I did this because in your example you in that line was loading a view called 'home'. setting this as a var will enable you to use different templates on different pages.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider having a function that gets the details of a page by its name. This in-turn would run a function like getIdByName($page_name = false)

From there you would have the ID to pull from the database and get the correct page.

Comment: Could I have a quick example plz,  still confused